# Traverse and change property values in object

Tags: object, dictionary, traversal, lodash

I'd like a function that allows for three arguments: object literal, condition function, manipulate function.

Given the following object literal:

```
var data = {
  'name': 'thomas',
  'date': new Date(),
  'cars': [{
    'name': 'bugati veyron',
    'purchased_at': new Date()
  }]
}
```

The following condition variable:

```
function condition (value) {
  return (value instanceof Date)
}
```

The following manipulate Function:

```
var moment = require('moment')
function manipulate (value){
  return moment(value).format('x')
}
```

When put all together:

```
var result = DESIRED_FN(data, condition, manipulate)
```

Result would equal:

```
{
  'name': 'thomas',
  'date': 1441904309,
  'cars': [{
    'name': 'bugati veyron',
    'purchased_at': 1441904309
  }]
}
```

Is there a connivence function within lodash or another library that would have this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lodash you can easily create one of your own:

```
_.mixin({'condMod': function(data, condition, manipulate){
        return _.mapValues(data, function(val, b){
            return condition(val)?manipulate(val):val;
        })
    }
});
```

and call it like this:

```
_.condMod(data, condition, manipulate);
```